# How to remove High Charts Gird Lines

Tags: highcharts

I have the following High Chart  of type Bar. I did some online search on how to hide the grid lines , I was able to hide grid lines except first line. can anybody suggest me where i am the doing the mistake.

```
 HTML

 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

  $(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        width:300,
        height: 100,
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
            text: ''
        },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Wind', 'Flood', 'EQ'],
                         tickWidth: 0,


    },
    yAxis: {
       allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
         gridLineColor: 'transparent',
          minorGridLineWidth: 0
        },
   legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        }, legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
    labels:
    {
     enabled: false
      },
      exporting: { enabled: false },
    plotOptions: {



            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                minPointLength:10 ,
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [10],
          color: '#9CC7DC'
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [21],
                           color: '#72AFCD'

    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [31],
        color: '#1479ac'
    }]
});
)};
```

Comment: Hi, can you add a JSFiddle please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable axis line by setting [lineWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.lineWidth) parameter as 0.